# How to declare internal methods in exported APIs?

Tags: java, java-module

This issue is related to (but not duplicated by) [Why does compilation of public APIs leaking internal types not fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41180155/14731)

**How can one define enum methods that are only accessible from internal classes?**

Specifically:

- Users need to be able to pass `enum` values to other parts of the API.
- Depending on which `enum` value the user passed, internal classes need to invoke a different operation.
- To ensure that each `enum` value is mapped to an operation, we declare a method in the `enum`.

Implications:

- The `enum` must be `public` and exported.
- The internal classes must reside in a separate package than the `enum` to prevent them from getting exported.
- The `enum` method must be `public` for the internal classes to invoke it.

The only way I could think of preventing users from invoking the `public` method is have it reference a non-exported type. For example:

```
public enum Color
{
  RED
  {
    public void operation(NotExported ignore)
    {
      // ...
    }
  },
  GREEN,
  {
    public void operation(NotExported ignore)
    {
      // ...
    }
  },
  BLUE;
  {
    public void operation(NotExported ignore)
    {
      // ...
    }
  };

  /**
   * Carries out an internal operation.
   *
   * @param ignore prevent users from invoking this method
   */
  public abstract void operation(NotExported ignore);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I do that, the compiler complains that an exported API references a non-exported type. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alan Bateman [pointed out](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2017-October/013242.html) a [shared secret mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723089/14731) used by the JDK. This allows internal classes to share package-protected methods across packages without resorting to the use of reflection.